# Compare performance of Concurrent Dictionary with Dictionary+Locks

Tags: c#, performance, .net

I wanted to measure the performance of Concurrent Dictionary vs Dictionary+Locks in a multithreaded environment. So I created my own `SyncDict` class of type`<int,int[]>`. Whenever there is a key match, it adds the `int[]` array value to itself, it also locks the whole dictionary with `ReaderWriterLockSlim` while updating the value.

I replicated the whole code through Concurrent Dictionary and I am using `AddOrUpdate()` method.
 
Whole console app code can be found here https://dotnetfiddle.net/1kFbGy Just copy paste the code in console app to run. It will not run fiddle

After running both codes with the same inputs I see a considerable amount of difference in running time. For example for one particular run on my machine Concurrent dictionary took 4.5 seconds vs SyncDict took less than 1 second.

I would like to know any thoughts / suggestions explaining the above running time. Is there anything wrong am I doing here?

```
 class SyncDict<TKey>
    {
        private ReaderWriterLockSlim cacheLock;
        private Dictionary<TKey, int[]> dictionary;
        public SyncDict()
        {
            cacheLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
            dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, int[]>();
        }

        public Dictionary<TKey, int[]> Dictionary
        {
            get { return dictionary; }
        }

        public int[] Read(TKey key)
        {
            cacheLock.EnterReadLock();
            try
            {
                return dictionary[key];
            }
            finally
            {
                cacheLock.ExitReadLock();
            }
        }

        public void Add(TKey key, int[] value)
        {
            cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                dictionary.Add(key, value);
            }
            finally
            {
                cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }

        public AddOrUpdateStatus AddOrUpdate(TKey key, int[] value)
        {
            cacheLock.EnterUpgradeableReadLock();
            try
            {
                int[] result = null;
                if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out result))
                {
                    if (result == value)
                        return AddOrUpdateStatus.Unchanged;
                    else
                    {
                        cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
                        try
                        {
                            Parallel.For(0, value.Length,
                            (i, state) =>
                            {
                                result[i] = result[i] + value[i];
                            });
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
                        }
                        return AddOrUpdateStatus.Updated;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Add(key, value);
                    return AddOrUpdateStatus.Added;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                cacheLock.ExitUpgradeableReadLock();
            }
        }

        public void Delete(TKey key)
        {
            cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                dictionary.Remove(key);
            }
            finally
            {
                cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }

        public enum AddOrUpdateStatus
        {
            Added,
            Updated,
            Unchanged
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Comparison

- A comparison of performance of 2 classes only makes sense if both adhere to the same specification. Does your class do what a `ConcurrentDictionary` does?

#### Review

- Why would you allow access to the underlying dictionary? If you must allow it, return a [IReadOnlyDictionary](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlydictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8).
- Checking arguments before taking a lock prevents unnecessary locks on bad input.
- `AddOrUpdate` does not work; have you checked  `if (result == value)`?

```
int[] a = new int[]{ 0, 1 }; 
int[] b = new int[]{ 0, 1 }; 
Console.WriteLine(a == b);  // False
```

Or is this as designed?

- What is the purpose of this? What if both arrays have different size?

> ```
>  Parallel.For(0, value.Length,
>  (i, state) =>
>  {
>      result[i] = result[i] + value[i];
>  });
> ```